# Accessing the content at memeory address 0x0 will result in an undefined behavior?

Tags: c, gcc, arm

I tried to access **memory address 0**, which is defined as the **start address of my ROM**, to check that my configuration is correct and such region is accessible. But when I compile the code, the resulting disassembly shows that such operation is undefined.

It's true that 0 is NULL and might be treated as undefined, but is there any workaround for accessing the content at memory address 0?

Here is the test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    printf("%08X", *(unsigned int*)(0));
}
```

When compiled with arm gcc and option `-Os`, the resulting disassembly is got.

```
main:
        mov     r3, #0
        ldr     r3, [r3]
        .inst   0xe7f000f0
```

It can be seen that the code ends at `.inst   0xe7f000f0` and `printf` is not called.

The code can also be found [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/ErrWh64o3).

Comment: On smaller embedded systems where you can (and often must) access the whole memory space, and where there isn't an OS which forces protected and virtual memory onto your applications, then `0` is a perfectly fine address which can be dereferenced. Assuming there's actually is something at that address.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, this is my question.

Comment: When you say that "the resulting disassembly shows that such operation is undefined", what do you mean by that? The assembly you show seems perfectly fine.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The code `.inst   0xe7f000f0` is interpertted as `#udf 0` in eclipse disassembly. Note that a minor change is applied to the disassembly for gcc version issue. The disassembly does not call printf and will die at the code `.inst   0xe7f000f0`.

Comment: Well there's multiple design flaws at play here: your compiler port using 0 as the null pointer when C doesn't require that. As well as the incompetence of the people who have designed microcontrollers for the past 30 years and _knew_ very well about the  complete dominance of C for those microcontrollers, whi _knew_ about the use of null pointers in C, and _still_ decided to map registers to physical address zero.

Comment: You may be able to convince the compiler to cooperate with your wishes by using a volatile compound literal like this: `printf("%08X", *(unsigned int*)((volatile int){0}));`.

Comment: @IanAbbott I wonder how well-defined it is to use `volatile` for a compound literal however - what does that even mean? Does it mean "You have to give this compound literal a memory location" or "you cannot replace this compound literal with the value used in the initializer list" or both? Using `volatile` for the pointer cast & dereferencing would be well-defined for sure though.

Comment: @Lundin It's pretty much the same as `volatile int addr = 0;` `printf("%08X", *(unsigned int*)addr);`, using an implementation-defined conversion from `int` to `unsigned int *`. The code produced is a bit less efficient than it would be if an actual constant 0 could be used as an address because the volatile access cannot be optimized away.

Comment: @IanAbbott It's kind of sketchy to lvalue access `volatile int` as an `unsigned int` though, what happens then isn't properly covered by the strict aliasing rules. Signed and unsigned types may alias, but it doesn't cover qualifiers.

Comment: @Lundin It is being accessed as a `volatile int`, not as an `unsigned int`. The `int` value is then *converted* to an `unsigned int *` in an implementation-defined way.

Comment: It's worth remembering that "undefined" does *not* necessarily mean "wrong".  The C Standard doesn't define what happens if you try to access address 0 (or any absolute address, for that matter), but if you're doing embedded programming, for a target environment for which there's something interesting at address 0, you obviously need a well-defined way of accessing it, and your compiler ought to give it to you.  It sounds like this version of gcc, at least with the invocation options you're giving it, is not a good choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to map an object at absolute addess zero through your linker script and then access that object, instead of trying to create a pointer to address zero.

For ARM Cortex M it is very likely that the tool chain has already done this for you, in the form of the vector table + special registers from address zero and upwards. Simply use the identifiers provided by the tool chain instead, or in the unlikely event that such aren't available, make your own custom linker script and allocate variables at physical address 0.

---

As for the "language-lawyer" part of the question:

> It's true that 0 is NULL and might be treated as undefined, but is there any workaround for accessing the content at memory address 0?

Not exactly. `NULL` is a null pointer constant, `0` is a null pointer constant and either of those can be used to create a null pointer, like in your code when you cast `0` to an object pointer type.

See [What's the difference between null pointers and NULL?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/278657)  where I try to clear up the difference between null pointers, null pointer constants and the `NULL` macro.

As for dereferencing a null pointer, it *is* undefined behavior as per the spec for the unary `*` operator, 6.5.3/4:

> If an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary `*` operator is undefined